# colname returns first entry in database table, not the one selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a page that when the user clicks on a horse to see more info on that horse (referred by ID number in mysql table), it only returns the first record, NOT the one you chose.
The page is http://www.cbarlranch.com/?pg=forsale

```
<?php require_once('dbaseinfo.php'); ?>
<?php
//set variables
$colname_rsStallion = "1";
if (isset($HTTP_GET_VARS['ID'])) {
  $colname_rsStallion = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $HTTP_GET_VARS['ID'] : addslashes($HTTP_GET_VARS['ID']);}

//select database
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

//build the query
$query_rsStallion = 
 sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = '%s'", $colname_rsStallion);

//set more variables
$rsStallion = mysql_query($query_rsStallion, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsStallion = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsStallion);
$totalRows_rsStallion = mysql_num_rows($rsStallion);
?>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You need a `while` loop, then echo from thereon.

Answer (score 1):

Try using $_GET['ID'] rather than $HTTP_GET_VARS. If your IF fails the it will default to the record with ID = 1 (which is likely your first record)

Comment: OK. The $_GET['ID'] worked to make each horse come up when you click More Info. Thank you Fred!